# Is there any perfomance issues when inserting into a large SQL Server table which is being queried?

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, insert

I use SQL Server. I got a large table - millions of rows. And I iterate through them (`SELECT .. WHERE ..`). This is a long operation (and I assume can't be shorter).

So what am I asking is if there will be any problems to `insert` data `into` that table in the progress of `select`ing? If yes, what should I do to reduce that? Same questing for `update` command (with indexed parameters of course).

Comment: "millions of rows" = small table, please. BILLIONS is large.

Comment: why are you iterating through rows?

Comment: not me, sql does when i query for `select .. where date>XXX AND date<YYY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, absolutely.  A simple solution (if it's an acceptable trade off within your application) is to specify the NOLOCK locking hint.  IE:

select * from table with NOLOCK

The tradeoff is that you won't get a consistent read, but in many cases this isn't problem.

Comment: that's the same as using Read uncommitted

Comment: While NOLOCK can be applied on a per-table basis, read uncommitted is applied to the entire statement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will have performance, and more specifically, locking and blocking issues.  If your `SELECT` statements are using indexes, which they should be, these indexes will be locked every time that you `INSERT` data into the table.  Since the table is relatively large, the lock will probably be long enough to block your `SELECT` statements, and deadlocks are likely as well.

This might be a scenario where you need to re-evaluate your table structure, and possibly even consider denormalizing to avoid this.

You might also consider [Enabling Row Versioning-Based Isolation Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175095.aspx), assuming that you can throughly test the rest of your system to understand the impact.

Comment: if my table has billion records and i start" selecting *" and meanwhile a new record has been inserted ( not by me). will my select capture the new record ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir My understanding is that it depends... which pages have been read from the `select` statement vs which page the record was inserted into.

Comment: if it hasent reached the page where the record is , will my select get it ?

Comment: If the `insert` completes successfully, and doesn't block on any resource being used by the `select`, and the `select` hasn't yet read the page where the `insert` occurred, I believe that the new record will be included.  Let me see if I can find some official source for what I just said...

Comment: My `SELECT` statement does not use the indexes, because it takes the data from table by date range.

Comment: Otherwise, it might be helpful to use indexes on a datetime.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson are you there?

Comment: @AgentFire. You could create an unclustered index on the date column. You would also have to have the other columns you are selecting from that table in the index. But this way you can look through the dates very fast. the downside would be that inserts, updates and deletes would take a little bit longer.

Comment: @AgentFire What additional questions did you have?

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not a good idea to have long running queries on a database with frequent updates. This decrease performance significantly because of locking.

It might be a good idea to look into data warehouses and see if that is something that you could use. That would enable you to have the transactions on a separate database and the bulk load from it in to another database that would have your warehouse.

This would greatly improve performance for both inserts and queries. The trans-actional database could have no indexes, and the warehouse could have all the indexes you want.

You could also put the warehouse in a column store database. That would give you the best query time with the minimal effort because there isn't any need to create indexes in a column store, all you would have to do is to design the schema properly. The drawback with column stores is how ever that inserts, updates and deletes are very slow compared to relational databases. But bulk loading from the transactional database should do the trick. If you require the data to be very up to date, you could bulk load every few minutes. If you just need data from the previous day you could bulk load into the warehouse each night.

The possibilities are endless. If you want to look into column store warehouses you could try MonetDB. Its an open source column store so you could try it out and see if that's anything that suits you.

Answer (score 1):

Do not assume execution time can't be shorter. If you query a date range, an index on date is a **must!**
Solve your problem indexing on **date** field:

```
-- please use correct names for your_table and date_field --
CREATE INDEX index_name ON your_table date_field
```

Comment: That is actually my original idea but what is the query result will enumerate millions of rows (say, counting the average num value, or a sum). I still can't understand if there will be a blocking issue.

Comment: You could also try setting the isolation levels to read uncomitted

Comment: SELECTs outside transactions are atomic. bloking may occur transparently. So the best performance for SELECTs is good for overall perfomance

Answer (score 1):

Warehousing, as per @Gisli, is a good option: build a copy of the data elsewhere, and run your long-running queries there, freeing up the "main" database for OLTP processing.

If this is not an option, you can mess around with **snapshot isolation** (something I know about, but have never worked with personally). Esssentially, this will take a "snapshot" of the database at the point in time you start the query, and will execute the query as if no subsequent changes were made to the database, *even if changes are made to the database while the query is running.* More importantly, any such changes are "real" and permanent. Think of it like a short-term branching of your database.

The duration of the branch (snapshot) is where I get weak. I believe you can have the snapshot last for the duration of the query, which means you'd (possibly) never be able to get the same results for a given query twice (if the data changes while you are running it); or you can create a "saved" snapshot that can be re-used over and over until you get around to deleting it. Be wary with this, you don't want your system to get cluttered up with old forgotten branches of past data!

Answer (score 1):

There is no PROBLEM. SQL Serve is built to deal with this kind of situations, you just need to set the correct isolation level on the transactions.

There are several possible scenarios, for example, if you don't mind reading the data that is being inserted, set your isolation  level to read uncommited on your read transaction. If you are inserting values in a range and reading values on another range, you can use SERIALIZABLE.

Take a look at the possible isolation levels:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx
```

Comment: But having long running queries will affect performance significantly

Comment: However, `Read uncommitted` can do more than just read the data that is being inserted... since the index will be modified in his scenario, [he can also get duplicated or missing rows](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/news2/beware-the-nolock-hint).

Comment: hey Gisli! agree with you but he asked if it is a problem to do that. And it isn't. RDBMS are built specifically to deal with these kind of situations. That is why we use them instead of excel or text files to store our data. Long running queries are bad, of course, but they wont break the DB. The main point here is: yes, you can run inserts and updates at the same time without worrying about the integrity of your data. Thanks for the comment